# Ignore character while importing with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I could not find such an option in the documentation. A measuring device spits out everything in Excel:

```
    <>    A    B    C
 1
 2
 3
```

When I delete the "<>" characters manually everything works fine. Is there a way to circumvent that (without conversion to csv)?

I do:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheetname,skiprows=0,header=0,index_col=0)
```

`skiprow = 1` does not do the trick since pandas uses the first row as names. If I supply `names = list(range(1, 4))` the first data row is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on [Peruz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9872839/peruz) answer:-

For your case, using regex

`df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="(?<!<>)\s+", engine='python')`

This should read in the columns properly, except that the first column would be named `<> A`

To change this, simply alter the first column name

`df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.str.replace("<>\s", ""))`

In the regex expression, `\s+` matches any number of space characters except when preceded by whatever is mentioned in the negative lookaround denoted by `(?<!charceters_to_ignore)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
f = open(fname, 'r')
line1 = f.readline()
data1 = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', names=line1.replace(' #', '').split(), dtype=np.float)
```

You might have a different separator though.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  My first line is

```
# id x y ...
```

So pandas header keyword doesn't work. I did the following by reading it twice:

```
cos_phot_header = pd.read_csv(table, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, engine='python', nrows=1)
cos_plot_text_header = cos_phot_header.drop(0, axis=1).values.tolist()
cos_phot_data = pd.read_csv(table, skip_blank_lines=True, comment='#', 
               delim_whitespace=True, header=None, engine='python', names=cos_plot_text_header[0])
```

I don't understand why there is no such option in pandas to do this, it is a very common problem that everyone encounters. You can also read the table with no lines (nrows=0) and use .columns, but honestly I think it is an equally ugly solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `read_csv()` supports `regex`. You can avoid matching the white space if it is preceded by something (in your case #). Just as an example, avoiding "!":

```
sep='(?<!\\!)\s+'
```

if you want you could rename the column to remove the initial character and white space.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My first line is:

```
# id ra dec ...
```

Where `#` is the commenting-character in Python. `import_csv` thinks that `#` is a column header, but it's not.
The workaround I used was to define the headers manually:

```
headerlist = ['id', 'ra', 'dec', ...]  
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', index_col=False, header=0, names=headerlist)
```

Note that `index_col` is optional in regards to this problem.

If there is any option to ignore a certain character in header line, I haven't found it. Hope this solution can be improved upon.